# How can std::runtime_error::runtime_error(const std::string&) meet std::exception's requirement of throw()?

Tags: c++, exception-specification

`std::exception` requires that its constructor be `throw()`. Yet `std::runtime_error` accepts a `std::string` as its argument, which indicates that it's storing a `std::string` somewhere. Therefore, an assignment or copy construction has to be going on somewhere. And for `std::string`, that's not a `nothrow` operation.

How then does `runtime_error::runtime_error` meet `throw()`?

(For context, I'm implementing an exception type, and want to store a few `std::string`s from the call site, and I want to do it correctly...)

Comment: Without diving into library code, a simple solution would be to catch the thrown exception on the allocation failure, and fall back on some safe alternative, like a small buffer built into the type and truncating the result.

Comment: @Dennis: That won't work either, because the `string` gets default-constructed before you enter the constructor of `runtime_error`.

Comment: You assume it is storing a string directly, and not just an array of char objects. Also, being a library function, they know if a string can throw when default constructed.

Comment: @billy, it could also just have a properly aligned `char` array of `sizeof(std::string)`, then placement-new the string into that array, catching exceptions. This allows you to detect if the `string` constructor will throw without needing to resort to library implementation details

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sub>([Here's](http://codepad.org/EcX0Yaqf) the same thing in a minimal-ish testcase.)</sub>

---

`runtime_error::runtime_error(string const&)` doesn't need to meet `throw()`.

It doesn't inherit from or override `exception::exception()`, and by the time `string`'s copy constructor is invoked, `exception::exception()` has completed.

If copying the `string` were to throw an exception, this would unwind `runtime_error::runtime_error(string const&)` and then, I suppose, invoke `exception::~exception()`.

---

It's hard to directly show that there is no requirement of a derived ctor to meet a base ctor's exception specifier, but it is strongly implied by the following passage (which describes how the base's destructor is invoked, rather than passing the exception into the base constructor):

> `[2003: 15.2/2]` **An object that is partially constructed or
>   partially destroyed will have destructors executed for all of its
>   fully constructed subobjects, that is, for subobjects for which the
>   constructor has completed execution and the destructor has not yet
>   begun execution.** Should a constructor for an element of an automatic
>   array throw an exception, only the constructed elements of that array
>   will be destroyed. If the object or array was allocated in a
>   new-expression, the matching deallocation function (3.7.3.2, 5.3.4,
>   12.5), if any, is called to free the storage occupied by the object.

The only passage which comes even close to the scenario you presumed (and which I initially presumed) is the following.

> `[2003: 15.4/3]` If a virtual function has an exception-specification,
>   all declarations, including the definition, of any function that
>   overrides that virtual function in any derived class shall only allow
>   exceptions that are allowed by the exception-specification of the base
>   class virtual function.

But clearly `exception::exception()` is not a virtual function, and clearly `runtime_error::runtime_error(string const&)` does not override it.

(Note that this scenario *would* apply for a virtual destructor; accordingly, [you can see that, in libstdc++, `runtime_error::~runtime_error()` is `throw()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/libstdc++/api/a01044_source.html)).

Comment: Oh, so `std::exception` must be nothrow, but classes derived from `std::exception` may throw in their constructors?

Comment: The default constructor (and copy constructor) must be `nothrow`; the constructor accepting a string must not be. It seems you're using the signature of the default constructor to refer to all constructors?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: `exception` has no constructor accepting a string. `runtime_error` has no default constructor ([and that would not be required to be `nothrow` either](http://codepad.org/JvO2J1gB)).

Comment: About the update, see §18.8.1/2: "Each standard library class T that derives from class exception shall have a publicly accessible copy con- structor and a publicly accessible copy assignment operator that do not exit with an exception."

Comment: @Potatoswatter: OK, but this question is not about the copy constructor or copy assignment operator.

Comment: @Tomalak: Sorry, saying "default constructor" was a brain fart, but the copy constructor is the hard part, §18.8.1/2 still stands.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1933/discussion-between-potatoswatter-and-tomalak-geretkal)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: §18.8.1/2 is still irrelevant.

Comment: I really dislike that they suggest comment discussions be brought to chat. Comments are the perfect place to elaborate and work out kinks, *and keep a record of it*. Gr.

Comment: @GMan: Can't disagree with you there. I also hate seeing "let us continue this discussion in chat" when I really don't want to. It's not enforced by the technology, but "chat" _feels_ real-time, and I don't come on Stack Overflow to interact in real-time. So the feature _rushes me_.

Answer (score 7):

#### Update, 2015:

> Yet `std::runtime_error` accepts a `std::string` as its argument, which indicates that it's storing a `std::string` somewhere. Therefore, an assignment or copy construction has to be going on somewhere. And for `std::string`, that's not a `noexcept` operation.

`runtime_error` (and `logic_error`) are only required to accept an argument of type `std::string const &`. *They are not required to copy it.*

Use these overloads at your own peril. LLVM libc++ does not provide storage.

On the other hand, GNU libstdc++ tiptoes carefully to avoid running out of memory. It copies the contents of the string, but into the exception storage space, not into a new `std::string`.

Even then, it adds an `std::string&&` overload and uses `friend`ship to adopt the internal buffer of a `std::string` argument passed by rvalue, to conserve exception storage space too.

So that's your real answer: "Very carefully, if at all."

You could leverage GCC's generosity by using `std::runtime_error`s as members of your own exception class, storing one string each. This would still be useless on Clang, though.

#### Original answer, 2011. This is still true:

An exception during stack unwinding causes `terminate` to be called.

But constructing the object to be thrown is not part of unwinding, and is treated no differently from the code before the `throw` expression.

If `std::runtime_error::runtime_error( std::string const & )` throws `std::bad_alloc`, the `runtime_error` exception is lost (it never existed) and the `bad_alloc` is handled instead.

Demonstration: http://ideone.com/QYPj3

As for your own class storing `std::string`s from the call site, you'll want to follow §18.8.1/2:

> Each standard library class T that derives from class exception shall have a publicly accessible copy constructor and a publicly accessible copy assignment operator that do not exit with an exception.

This is required because copying from the stack to the thread's exception storage *is* sensitive to exceptions. §15.1/7:

> If the exception handling mechanism, after completing evaluation of the expression to be thrown but before the exception is caught, calls a function that exits via an exception, std::terminate is called (15.5.1).

So, you should use a `shared_ptr< std::string >` or some such to sanitize copies *after* the first.