# What requirements does the standard place upon a type thrown in an exception?

Tags: c++, exception

[I thought exceptions imposed a bit more on the thrown type than the standard actually imposes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864011/how-can-stdruntime-errorruntime-errorconst-stdstring-meet-stdexception) I want to clear up this confusion. What is actually imposed on those types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ ISO spec, §15.1/3, states that

> The type of the throw-expression shall not be an
>   incomplete type, or a pointer or reference to an incomplete type, other than void*, const void*, volatile void*, or const volatile void*. Except for these restrictions and the restrictions on type matching mentioned in 15.3, the operand of throw is treated exactly as a function argument in a call (5.2.2) or the operand of a return statement.

From this, it seems that you should be able to throw anything you'd like, as long as you're not throwing a type that you've only forward-declared.

**EDIT**: As @Billy ONeal points out, the type must be copyable, which means that it should support a copy constructor.

Comment: I think it needs a copy constructor anyway, given 15.1 paragraph 3 `A throw-expression initializes a temporary object, called the exception object`

Comment: @Billy ONeal- Thanks for pointing that out!  I'll update my answer.